# How to destroy the First Window?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, destroy

I am making the GUI Chat Program using the following Steps as following:

1. the Login (the chat_login.py)->
2. the Chatting Windows(the chat_client_testG.py)

After the Login is successful, the First Window has not been destroyed.
(OS : window 7, Python 2.7)

Please, help me to destroy the First Window successfully!!

chat_login.py:

```
from socket import *
import thread, time
import msvcrt as m
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext
import os 
import sys

login_w = Tk()
login_w.title("The SCH Chat-Client V0.1")

login_w.geometry('400x100')

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) 
id_label = Label(login_w,text=" I D : " )
id_label.grid(column=0, row=0)

id_txt = Entry(login_w)
id_txt.grid(row=0, column=1)

pass_label = Label(login_w,text="Password : " )
pass_label.grid(column=0, row=1)

pass_txt = Entry(login_w)
pass_txt.grid(row=1, column=1)

def recvMsg(sock):
    while True:
            recvmsg = sock.recv(1024)

def Con_Clicked():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 8008
    print host
    try:

        s.connect((host, 8008))
        thread.start_new_thread(recvMsg, (s, )) 
        time.sleep(1)
        nickmsg = id_txt.get()
        s.send(nickmsg)
        time.sleep(2)
        print 'Wait!'
                os.system('python chat_client_testG.py')

    except:
        print "Wrong address!"

con_btn = Button(login_w, text="Login" , command = Con_Clicked )
con_btn.grid(column=0, row=2)

login_w.mainloop()
```

Comment: print 'Wait!'
                os.system('python chat_client_testG.py') exit()